# how to open PDF in android using pdfview

Tags: java, android

I am using  android-pdfview-1.0.2.jar I found it [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca:%22android-pdfview%22) Link to the main project is [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) I am trying to load PDF as follows

```
PDFView pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
pdfView.fromAsset("sample.pdf")
.defaultPage(1)
.showMinimap(false)
.enableSwipe(true)
.onLoad(this)
.onPageChange(this)
.load();
```

I have added pdfView in my layout as shown below

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

while executing I am getting following error:

```
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vudroid from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.klouddata.pdffileexample-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.klouddata.pdffileexample-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:359)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at org.vudroid.core.VuDroidLibraryLoader.load(VuDroidLibraryLoader.java:13)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfContext.<clinit>(PdfContext.java:13)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:50)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:31)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-12 17:10:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Where is your asynctask code?

Comment: I don't have any asynctask in my code

Comment: It shows in your exception that `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask` and `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

Comment: yeah I can see that. But trust me I haven't used asynctask

Comment: The important part of the stack trace is 
`
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vudroid from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.klouddata.pdffileexample-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.klouddata.pdffileexample-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]`

Comment: @DCoder I got error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available" . Would you like to give me working sample!? plz

Comment: Can you please provide the complete class definition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved problem by adding armeabi-v7a folder which can be found [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview/libs)

now sample.pdf looks like
[image]

Comment: Hi @DCoder have you encountered when displaying the pdf it is always horizontal? How did you solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy paste the folders to your libs dir ?
Or is it the .so file itself ?