# Android pdfrenderer not working properly with 19 or 21 minsdk

Tags: android, pdfrenderer

Making a program for Android L' using pdfrenderer the issue is

1. when 'm running the emulator with `minsdk = 21` 
   ERROR - "`emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.andro_pdf_two.MainActivity activity launch'!`"
2. when 'm trying to run the emulator at minsdk = 19 
   ERROR at logcat- `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer` 
   and `Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer#openPage`

I have done everything as suggested - **resetting adb**, **resetting preferences**...but nothing seems to be working can anyone help???

Comment: I've added the pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar as an external JAR to my java GWT project.

Answer (score 1):

Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer#openPage

clearly states that you need a min sdk version of 21 and your app has a current api level of 19

set this in your manifest and try

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: Thanx, but still with minsdk = 21 ERROR msg- "emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.andro_pdf_two.MainActivity activity launch'...what can i do to fix it??

Comment: Pls install android Lolipop Sdk first and use an emulator which uses the 5.0 sdk

Comment: I have already installed wat was required..in sdk manager but still its shows the same error..cant post snapshot of sdk manager..any other suggestions...?

Comment: Still the same error - " emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.andro_pdf_two.MainActivity activity launch'!"

Comment: Even if you install the Lolipop SDK in the sdk manager it does not mean that your emulator will be running lollipop. Create a new emulator that runs a lollipop image. The error message you are getting is telling you that you are trying to run an application that requires a min sdk of 21 onto a device thats 19.

Answer (score 0):

PDFRenderer assumes minimum API level - 21.

You can use [android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) for API level less than 21.

Comment: These are all PDF viewer apps, not libraries. How is this supposed to help OP?

Comment: Each library has its corresponding viewer. I have used android-pdfview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183472/how-to-open-pdf-in-android-using-pdfview

Comment: Again, these links are apps, not libraries. Yes, android-pdfview is a library, which you just added to the list, and is the only correct answer. The rest are of no help.